# Swift & Core Data - Adding an entity to an existing entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I understand questions regarding Core Data and relationships occur a lot, but this one's different I promise :)

I have two tables, a 'Job' table and a 'Scheme' table.

The scheme table is populated when the app loads, all good so far.

I understand that when I create a new 'Job' I need to fetch the right 'Scheme' and then attach that Scheme to the Job.

My trouble is, is I am already inside a temporary context while that Fetch is occurring, it just results in a nil unwrapping error and falls over, I think it's to do with me trying to perform a fetchRequest while an operation is already pending on my managedObjectContext...

Heres some code that should outline where I'm at:

```
for (index, object) in obj {

                    let entityName = "Job"
                    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
                    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", object["id"].string!)

                    var error: NSError?
                    if let results = tempContext.executeFetchRequest(
                        request,
                        error: &error
                        ) as? [NSManagedObject] {
                            if results.count != 0{

                                if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
                                    moc.performBlockAndWait({

                                        for result in results {

                                            self.refreshDataSet(result, object: object)
                                             moc.save(nil)
                                        }

                                    })

                                }


                            }else{
                                if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
                                    moc.performBlockAndWait({

                                        self.createJobData(object, moc: moc)
                                         moc.save(nil)
                                    })                                  
                                }
                          }
                    }

                }
```

So, inside the `self.createJobData(object, moc: moc)` bit is this:

```
 func createJobData(object: JSON, moc: NSManagedObjectContext){

    let work = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Work

    let schemeEntity = "Scheme"
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: schemeEntity)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", object["schemeId"].string!)


    self.managedObjectContext!.performBlock { () -> Void in
        var error: NSError?
        if let results = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(
            request,
            error: &error
            ) as? [Scheme] {
                if results.count != 0{
                    for result in results{
                        println(result)
                    }

                }

        }

    }
```

//....

}

and thats where I get confused, I tried adding another performBlock but then realised that wasn't the answer obviously...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried refactoring without blocks, and just using the main thread managed object context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend doing everything on the main thread context. If you cannot do that, do everything on the **same** background context.

If you are using a fetched results controller, it will do the lookup for you. Presumably your user has *selected* a `Scheme`, so

```
let scheme = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Scheme
```

Use the same managed object context:

```
let context = scheme.managedObjectContext // or get it from your Core Data stack
let newJob = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
                 "Job", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Job 
newJob.scheme = scheme
do { try context.save() } catch { /*handle error */ }
```